# MS Access and Pass Through queries on remote desktop

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, remote-desktop, pass-through

I apologize if this is in the wrong place, but this is my first post and I have quite a specific issue that I hope someone else has experienced before.

**Here is a little background:**

I have created an access database to use as our companies' CRM, its an access front end and SQL backend.

Over the last few months, I  have converted most queries to pass through queries due to the performance increase.

We have also just migrated to a remote desktop environment from the more traditional set up of a local server and workstations.

**The issue:**

Now we are using RDS there is only 1 central installation of MS access and my accdb file that all users open as they log into RDS (I have been told this is normal)

However, when VBA code fires to change the querydef of a pass-through query, it changes the query globally for all users, so users are sometimes presented with incorrect results.

Strangely, I also use TempVars to store things, but these DO stay unique for each user.

**Example:**

The users have a daily tasks screen on their home page, the event onload on the home screen sets the querydef to include the parameter for that user's ID number, but as users log in, previously logged in users end up seeing the tasks for the last user to log in.

I hope all this makes sense and I hope someone can help

Comment: My guess is that you have static variables that are being shared by all users, but without seeing a sample of the relevant code, it will be very difficult to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of the frontend for each user. Place it in a subfolder of the users %localappdata% folder.

Create a shortcut to open the application. In this, use the %localappdata% in the command line.

Then all users will run their own copy not seen by the other users.

Answer (score 0):

RDS or not,having all the users opening the same FE has drawbacks, in performance, and other matters. I suppose every users has his own VM ? Then just put a copy of the FE on each VM.

Or even better: give them a shortcut to open the app. The shortcut should:
- launch a small script that copies the FE from the deployment folder to their c:\temp folder
- lauch the FE from there

This way, updates will be transparent for your users. However this solution is not valid if you keep some static data in the FE.